# Exists statement in SQL returns an array within an array with the key of the useful data as the query itself in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli, exists

I have an SQL statement:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id=123456)
```

Written in PHP using the [PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class), this looks like so:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE property_id=123456)');
print_r($results);
```

With `$results` looking like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id=123455)] => 1 ) )
```

The only useful part of that array is the 1 near the end indicating that the row was found.

The way I would normally think to access this is with

```
$found = $results[0]['EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id=123455)'];
```

which frankly seem ridiculous, and to boot doesn't work.

How might I access this value, preferably in the most elegant way?

Comment: Do not use this class. It's buggy and insecure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to use an alias using `AS`.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE property_id=123456) AS `exists`
```

Then you can use,

```
$found = $results[0]['exists'];
```

Comment: This is right but uses the protected keyword exists so is invalid, but good shout!

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime That's why I escaped it with backticks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Give an alias to your selected value - that will become your index:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE property_id=123456) AS result');
print_r($results);
```

will produce in

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [result] => 1 ) )
```

And you can then get your specific value with:

```
$found = $results[0]['result'];
```

Note that you will always get a two-dimensional result, as the first dimension is the row number.

Comment: Somebody's definitely having a bad day - downvoting every valid answer on the question

Answer (score -2):

Apart from the fact that class you are using is buggy and insecure, it is inconvenient too. What you really need is just one line

```
$found = $db->getOne('SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE property_id=?i',123456);
```

using [safeMysql class](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/)

Note that `exists` is useless her and it is not responsible for the returning nested arrays. It is class you are using to blame.

Comment: The class I am using supports this same functionality. I trust the values I am supplying so am using the simplest type of statement. Can you provide details of why PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class is buggy and I will consider whether or not it's appropriate for future use.

Comment: It's a pity you are making statements without reading my answer.

Comment: Buggy, insecure, not to your liking -  I use all synonymously. Can you explain your concerns with it? The lack of getOne isn't an issue for me at this time. It would be more inconvenient to start using a different class mid project if that's influencing your views.

Comment: Well, keep using it then.

Comment: You should probably explain "... class you are using is buggy and insecure" else you may want to edit that part of your answer so as not to mislead.

Comment: "exists is useless here" - exists is the foundation of what I'm trying to do? Just interested as to what you might mean.

Comment: you can simply omit exists and get exactly the same result as shown in my code.